# Cron is working but Last heartbeat is older than one hour

Tags: magento-1.9, cron

we have 2 sites on the same server.

we have a custom module to check if the cron is working or not.

in one site we are getting the below message

[image]

in another site, this message:

[image]

**Is there any other way to check if the cron is working or not except AOE scheduler extension** ?

[image]

**cron.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * Magento
 *
 * NOTICE OF LICENSE
 *
 * This source file is subject to the Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
 * that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE.txt.
 * It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
 * http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php
 * If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
 * obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
 * to license@magento.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
 *
 * DISCLAIMER
 *
 * Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade Magento to newer
 * versions in the future. If you wish to customize Magento for your
 * needs please refer to http://www.magento.com for more information.
 *
 * @category    Mage
 * @package     Mage
 * @copyright  Copyright (c) 2006-2015 X.commerce, Inc. (http://www.magento.com)
 * @license    http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php  Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
 */

// Change current directory to the directory of current script
chdir(dirname(__FILE__));


require 'app/Mage.php';

if (!Mage::isInstalled()) {
    echo "Application is not installed yet, please complete install wizard first.";
    exit;
}

// Only for urls
// Don't remove this
$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] = str_replace(basename(__FILE__), 'index.php', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] = str_replace(basename(__FILE__), 'index.php', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']);

Mage::app('admin')->setUseSessionInUrl(false);

umask(0);

$disabledFuncs = explode(',', ini_get('disable_functions'));
$isShellDisabled = is_array($disabledFuncs) ? in_array('shell_exec', $disabledFuncs) : true;
$isShellDisabled = (stripos(PHP_OS, 'win') === false) ? $isShellDisabled : true;
$isShellDisabled = true;

try {
    if (stripos(PHP_OS, 'win') === false) {
        $options = getopt('m::');
        if (isset($options['m'])) {
            if ($options['m'] == 'always') {
                $cronMode = 'always';
            } elseif ($options['m'] == 'default') {
                $cronMode = 'default';
            } else {
                Mage::throwException('Unrecognized cron mode was defined');
            }
        } else if (!$isShellDisabled) {
            $fileName = basename(__FILE__);
            $baseDir = dirname(__FILE__);
            shell_exec("/bin/sh $baseDir/cron.sh $fileName -mdefault 1 > /dev/null 2>&1 &");
            shell_exec("/bin/sh $baseDir/cron.sh $fileName -malways 1 > /dev/null 2>&1 &");
            exit;
        }
    }

    Mage::getConfig()->init()->loadEventObservers('crontab');
    Mage::app()->addEventArea('crontab');
    if ($isShellDisabled) {
        Mage::dispatchEvent('always');
        Mage::dispatchEvent('default');
    } else {
        Mage::dispatchEvent($cronMode);
    }
} catch (Exception $e) {
    Mage::printException($e);
    exit(1);
}

?>

<?php
Mage::log('cron working', null, 'cron.log');
?>
```

command :

```
*/5 * * * * /usr/bin/php  -q /var/www/html/sitename/cron.php
```

**Edit **

when i add this code at the end of cron.php , and run the file in browser, it showed : `Tuesday 17th of May 2016 07:12:03 PM` so seems cron is running. but **why Heartbeat not found ?**

```
try {
   $myFile = "cronlog.txt";
   $fh = fopen($myFile, 'w');
   $stringData = date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A');
   fwrite($fh, $stringData);
   fclose($fh);
} catch (Exception $e) {
   Mage::printException($e);
}
```

Comment: Have you checked your system.log and exception.log (if logging is active)?

Comment: @JulienLachal let me check & inform you.

Comment: @JulienLachal sorry for delay , i checked log folders, until now no error related to cron is generated. but i selected all tasks and clicked on 
"Run now" under Action column ,, now its displaying like this : http://prnt.sc/b53b3b means its displaying in green color.

Comment: So everything is fine again?

Comment: @JulienLachal before it was displaying green color, after one hour again its displaying in red color that `" Last heartbeat is older than one hour"`

Comment: Do you have a way to know if the PHP command was actually executed by your server?

Comment: @JulienLachal when i run this command : `*/5 * * * * /usr/bin/php  -q /var/www/html/sitename/cron.php >` i got "new mail root". but i am not sure , its really working or not.

Comment: @JulienLachal i updated the question. seems 99 % cron is working. but no heartbeat found.

Comment: try just to execute `/usr/bin/php /var/www/html/sitename/cron.php` Maybe there is an exception raised and if so, it should be printed out either in the console or in the var/report directory. You can also call the cron.php file in your browser, but if you applied all latest patches you first have to allow it (temporarily)

Comment: @DavidVerholen i called the cron.php file in browser, than it created cronlog.text file and it displayed date as `Tuesday 17th of May 2016 07:12:03 PM` so, is cron is working fine right ? i guess it problem with aoe scheduler extension ?

Comment: the cron.php file should still work with aoe scheduler (i think) although its recommended to execute the cron.sh over the shell. The aoe scheduler actually brings its own execution script (smth. like scheduler_cron.sh) in newer versions which ships with some additional functionality. Maybe you want to try execute it like this in your crontab: `* * * * * /bin/sh /var/www/html/sitename/scheduler_cron.sh`

Comment: @DavidVerholen i installed almost recent version of  Aoe scheduler, but `scheduler_cron.sh` file is not there. is i need to install again to get `scheduler_cron.sh` file ?

Comment: you can find the latest version on github which includes the file: https://github.com/AOEpeople/Aoe_Scheduler

Comment: heres the link to download the latest release: https://github.com/AOEpeople/Aoe_Scheduler/archive/v1.3.1.zip

Comment: @DavidVerholen i installed new extension & executed cron.sh command, but still no luck for me.